# how to check how many times 'a' shows?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, char, compare

```
int main (void)
{
    char input[99999];

    int  times=0;
    int  words=0,a=0;

    while ((input[a]=getchar()) != EOF) // get input
        {
        a++;
        }
    for (int n=0;n<=a;n++)
    {
        if(input[n]<='z' && input[n]>='a' ){words++;}       
    }
    float freq=times/words;

    for(char letter ='a'; letter<='z'; letter++)
    {
        for (int n=0;n<=a;n++)
        {
            if(input[n]==letter){times++;}
        }
        printf( "%c %.4f\n", letter, freq); 
    }
}
```

and i got results:

```
asdf a
a 0.0000
b 0.0000
c 0.0000
d 0.0000
e 0.0000
f 0.0000
g 0.0000
h 0.0000
i 0.0000
j 0.0000
k 0.0000
l 0.0000
m 0.0000
n 0.0000
o 0.0000
p 0.0000
q 0.0000
r 0.0000
s 0.0000
t 0.0000
u 0.0000
v 0.0000
w 0.0000
x 0.0000
y 0.0000
z 0.0000
```

Comment: Write a program that calculates the frequency of letter occurrences in text.

Comment: i dont know why |if(input[n]==letter){times++;}| doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

You have three big issues in your code:

1. You're computing `freq` in the wrong place. Your taking `times/words` when `times` is still 0. (You haven't assigned anything to it since initialization.) This needs to instead go at the end of the `for` loop.
2. You're not setting `times` back to 0 on each iteration of the `for` loop, so it's cumulative. (If you have 3 `a`s and 4 `b`s, `times` will be 7 after the `b` iteration.)
3. You're using integer division, but you need to convert the numerator to a float first: `(float)times / words`.

I did some other cleanup, like renaming `words` to `letters` and `a` to `length`, since those seemed to be better reflections of what those variables are doing. Below is a complete working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char input[99999];

    int letters = 0, length = 0;

    while ((input[length++] = getchar()) != EOF);

    for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
    {
        if (input[n] >= 'a' && input[n] <= 'z')
        {
            letters++;
        }       
    }

    for(char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++)
    {
        int times = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
        {
            if (input[n] == letter)
            {
                times++;
            }
        }

        float freq = (float)times / letters;
        printf("%c %.4f\n", letter, freq);
    }
}
```

Example output when the string "hello" is piped to the program:

```
a 0.0000
b 0.0000
c 0.0000
d 0.0000
e 0.2000
f 0.0000
g 0.0000
h 0.2000
i 0.0000
j 0.0000
k 0.0000
l 0.4000
m 0.0000
n 0.0000
o 0.2000
p 0.0000
q 0.0000
r 0.0000
s 0.0000
t 0.0000
u 0.0000
v 0.0000
w 0.0000
x 0.0000
y 0.0000
z 0.0000
```

**UPDATE**

Note that your solution is fairly inefficient. You need to read each character of the input 26 times (once for each letter).

You could instead use an array of 26 counts and update them all in one pass through the input. Here's one possibility for that solution:

## include

## include

```
int main (void)
{
    char input[99999];
    int counts[26] = { 0 };
    int length = 0, total = 0;

    while ((input[length++] = getchar()) != EOF);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = tolower(input[i]);
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            counts[c - 'a'] += 1;
            total += 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (counts[i] > 0) {
            printf("%c %.4f\n", 'a' + i, (float)counts[i] / total);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wt if count both 'A' and 'a' for once 'a'?   can still use this method?

Comment: then counts[input[i]-'A' ]  ?

Comment: @BEIXIN Exactly. Either convert to lowercase first, or check which range it's in and subtract the right amount.

Comment: @BEIXIN I've updated my last code snippet to convert each character to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char input[99999];  
    int a=0;
    float  words=0.0,times=0;

    while ((input[a]=getchar()) != EOF) // get input
        {
        a++;
        }
    for (int n=0;n<=a;n++)
    {
        if(input[n]<='z' && input[n]>='a' ){words++;}       
    }
    float freq=0;

    for(char letter ='a'; letter<='z'; letter++)
    {
        for (int n=0;n<=a;n++)
        {
            if(input[n]==letter){times++;}
        }
        freq=times/words;
        if(freq!=0){printf( "%c %.4f\n", letter, freq); }
        times=0;
    }

}
```